# Signal not waking waiting thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I use monitor and condition variables for synchronizing thread, I have a thread that should wait until the other thread signal it,but the signal does not Wake up the waiting thread.
If a thread wait,the "thread wait" appears but when a thread signal to that waiting thread "thread signaled" does not appear.
here is my code:

```
try {
    worker = new monitorun(request, mainWebs, charge, S, executor, second1, lock1, m1);
    Thread th = new Thread(worker);

    while (charge2 <= 0 && m1.get(str4[1]) < 1000) {
        try {
            System.err.println("thread wait");
            m3.get(str4[1]).await();
            System.err.println("thread signaled");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lock1.lock();
    try {
        charge = m1.get(str4[1]) + charge2;

        th.start();
        m1.remove(str4[1]);
        m1.put(str4[1], charge);

        if (m1.get(str4[1]) >= 1000) {
            m3.get(str4[1]).signal();
            System.out.println("signal");

        }
    } finally {
        lock1.unlock();
    }

} finally {
    lock1.unlock();

    b = false;
}
```

Comment: What is m3? A list of Strings?

Comment: You need to put the signal code in another thread. The signal function is never called because the thread is waiting().

Comment: I got it,this code is in an extends Thread class.

Comment: I have three classes,the first one get a request from web server,the second is extends Thread that just process that request and create a thread for that request,the last class send answer to the web server.